# Help me Solve this Steady State 2-D Heat equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, heat-equation

[image: Problem Statement]

So I tried to solve this PDE by separation of variables which was not applicable because of non-homogeneous nature of this PDE. Then I assumed ( after reading from a book ) :

$$ T(x,y)=v(x,y) + \phi(x) $$

After this, I solved the equation and got

$$ v(x,y)=0$$
and
$$ \phi(x)=-x^2+5.5x $$

Please tell me the error and give me the direction to solve this problem myself.

Comment: Hint: Let $T(x,y) = u(x,y) - 0.5 x$